# Web Scraping with BS4, how to set a range of where to look

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the "Events" section of this wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020. The page does not have the easiest HTML to navigate as most of the tags are not nested, but are siblings.

I want to ensure that the only data I scrape is between the two h2 tags shown below.
Here is the condensed HTML:

```
<h2>                  #I ONLY WANT TO SEARCH BETWEEN HERE
    <span id="Events">Events</span>
</h2>
<h3>...</h3>
<ul>...</ul>
<h3>...</h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a title="June 17"</a>   #My code below is looking for this, if not found it jumps to another section
    </li>
</ul>
<h3>...</h3>
<ul>...</ul>
<h2>                 #AND HERE. DON"T WANT TO GO PAST HERE
    <span id="Predicted_and_scheduled_events">Predicted_and_scheduled_events</span>
</h2>
```

If it's not clear, every tag(except for span) is a sibling. My code currently works if the date is present between the two h2 tags, however if the date is not present it will go to another section of the page to pull data, which I do not want.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import requests
import bs4
res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
todaysNews = soup.find('a', {"title": "June 17"}) #goes to date's stories
```

Comment: BS has siblings function - [Going sideways](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways). BTW: BS has many useful functions and  it is worth reading the whole documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BS has many useful functions and parameters. It is worth reading the whole documentation.

It has function to get parent element, next siblings, elements which have any title, etc.

---

First I search `<span id="Events">Events</span>`, next I get its `parent` element `<h2>` and I have start of data.

Next I can get `next_siblings` and run in `for`-loop until I get item with name `h2` and I get end of data.

In `for`-loop I can check all `ul` elements and search direct `li` element without nested `li` elements (`recursive=False`), and inside `li` I can get first `a` which has `title` with any text (`{"title": True}`)

```
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

# found start of data `h2`
start = soup.find('span', {'id': 'Events'}).parent

# check sibling items
for item in start.next_siblings:

    # found end of data `h2`
    if item.name == 'h2': 
        break

    if item.name == 'ul':

        # only direct `li` without nested `li`
        for li in item.find_all('li', recursive=False): 

            # `a` which have `title`
            a = li.find('a', {'title': True}) 

            if a:
                print(a['title'])
```

Result:

```
January 1
January 2
January 3
January 5
January 7
January 8
January 9
January 10
January 12
January 16
January 18
January 28
January 29
January 30
January 31
February 5
February 11
February 13
February 27
February 28
February 29
March 5
March 8
March 9
March 11
March 12
March 13
March 14
March 16
March 17
March 18
March 20
March 23
March 24
March 26
March 27
March 30
April 1
April 2
April 4
April 5
April 6
April 7
April 8
April 9
April 10
April 12
April 14
April 15
April 17
April 18
April 19
April 20
April 21
April 22
April 23
April 25
April 26
April 27
April 28
April 29
April 30
May 1
May 3
May 4
May 5
May 6
May 7
May 9
May 10
May 11
May 12
May 14
May 15
May 16
May 18
May 19
May 21
May 22
May 23
May 24
May 26
May 27
May 28
May 30
May 31
June 1
June 2
June 3
June 4
June 6
June 7
June 8
June 9
June 16
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector with `","` and then check for tag name.

CSS selector `h2:contains("Events") ~ ul > li` will select all `ul > li` siblings to `<h2>` which contains string `"Events"`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('h2:contains("Events") ~ ul > li, h2:contains("Predicted and scheduled events")'):
    if tag.name == 'li':
        print(tag.a.text)
    else:
        break
```

Prints:

```
January 1
January 2
January 3
January 5
January 7
January 8
January 9
January 10
January 12
January 16
January 18
January 28
January 29
January 30
January 31
February 5
February 11
February 13
February 27
February 28
February 29
March 5
March 8
March 9
March 11
March 12
March 13
March 14
March 16
March 17
March 18
March 20
March 23
March 24
March 26
March 27
March 30
April 1
April 2
April 4
April 5
April 6
April 7
April 8
April 9
April 10
April 12
April 14
April 15
April 17
April 18
April 19
April 20
April 21
April 22
April 23
April 25
April 26
April 27
April 28
April 29
April 30
May 1
May 3
May 4
May 5
May 6
May 7
May 9
May 10
May 11
May 12
May 14
May 15
May 16
May 18
May 19
May 21
May 22
May 23
May 24
May 26
May 27
May 28
May 30
May 31
June 1
June 2
June 3
June 4
June 6
June 7
June 8
June 9
June 16
```